# Does Android system update backups the current kernel and root file system during the process?

Tags: android

We are designing the update process of an embedded device. The idea is to boot into a ramdisk and copy the contents to the flash. That part is done and works well, but we have no measures to ensure that the device does not gets unusable if, i.e, the battery runs out, apart from just preventing to start the update if the battery is below some threshold.

So we have started to think about the possiblity of having a backup of the main files (basically the kernel and the rootfs) to restore them in case something goes wrong. Looking at Android, which is very similar to our case, I wonder if it does the backup, or it just copies the new partition contents, relying on the recovery kernel to fix things but without returning automatically to the previous state (before the update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Android system update backups the current kernel and root file system during the process?

No. It just restores the apps and some data. If your app is going to root or something else - it's other story but it is irrelevant and it does not matter in regards of backup. [See here more information about platform backup feature](https://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html).